# How to fix visibility ValueError from load_workbook in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm working with openpyxl to open a excel sheet to use. Here's the line where I call load_workbook.

```
new_bk = load_workbook(BytesIO(fname), data_only=True)
```

However, recently, I've been getting error on some of my excel files

```
value = 'show'
ValueError: Value must be one of {'veryHidden', 'visible', 'hidden'}
```

I'm aware that the expected options relate to sheet visibility options. However, for some reason, some of the excel files I'm using have the 'show' option. Is there a way to fix this? Maybe an option in load_workbook that let's me manual set the visibility option.

EDIT:
On further research, I think that the issue seems to be that the openpyxl ChildSheet instance being created is getting a value of 'show'
[see ChildSheet class here](https://%20https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/packaging/workbook.html)

I'm not sure why. Could it be an updated excel version?

Comment: You need to provide a more complete code example - it's unclear what `value` is in your example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `show` isn't a valid setting.